How to Create a Neural Network Model to Generate Dance Movements Based on Music in MMD Format
I am working on a project where I need to create a neural network model to generate dance movements based on music. My goal is to achieve results similar to this video: https://youtu.be/FrA7f5F9TsI

The motion file (in .vmd or MMD format) contains data about body joint movements (bones). Each bone has 3 rotation values in space (x, y, z). One second of an MMD file contains 30 frames, with each frame recording the values for all bones




To reduce the data volume, I have taken the following steps:

Increased the audio duration to a whole second (159.8 -> 160.0) so that the Mel spectrogram steps have clear data within a second. The same applies to MMD. Extended by setting empty values at the end
Reduced the number of MMD bones from 100 to 25, keeping those that generate 90% of movements
Reduced the frame rate from 30 to 10
Using only one character
This is how it looks after all the limitations: 
Audio: Using a limited Mel spectrogram with a range from 0 to 5000 Hz. Parameters: n_mels = 200, n_fft = 4096, hop_length = 735000 (3 steps per second) (Length 160 seconds = 480 steps).



Data Preparation for the Neural Network:
To prepare the data, I divided all iterations of the training files into seconds so they fit into memory and can be processed on a GPU (4070)

Normalization: For the spectrogram from 0 to 1. For MMD from -1 to 1 (with adjustments for their features)

For input, I can use the Mel spectrogram, any part of it (e.g., 2 past, 1 current, and 5 future seconds). I can also use several past seconds of MMD (e.g., 0 or 3) and any other information (the idea of adding past MMD to the input is to have continuity with past results when generating new iterations).

For output, I use the currently processed second of MMD, which is what I want to generate



I have tried various model combinations, such as LSTM and Attention, but the models always stop training. The latest settings and data I trained with can be found here. Parameters: 1 second of Mel spectrogram before, 1 current; 1 second of previous MMD. The output is 1 current second. MMD source - as in the video.
I have all the necessary data, but I cannot get the model to work. Any ideas or advice on improving the model or training process would be greatly appreciated.
